# Why does Ubuntu 11.10 hang frequenty?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

I've been using Ubuntu from a long time and recently I have shifted to its newest version 11.10. Its interface is nice but my touch-pad hangs frequently in short intervals of time. When that happens, no key or key combination works. The only option is to restart or logout my laptop. I am using a Dell Inspiron N4010.

I have tried a lot to solve this problem but haven't found any satisfactory help till now. Most of my friends who are using Ubuntu 11.10 reported the same to me, seems like it's a bug.

How can I get out of this problem?

Comment: More detail is better, like what kind of touchpad...

Comment: I am using Dell Insipiron 14 R N4010 model.

Comment: Check if someone has reported a similar bug. If not, report one. [Follow the recommendations here.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your Ubuntu? Update will be a good option. I have had issues with the unity desktop and compiz, So i installed gnome and nautilus instead and removed compiz. That seems to have helped.

To install gnome

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

nautilus also can be installed similarly.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus.
```